# How do I navigate to an Ember Route within my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-rails

I have a very complex interactive page as part of a Rails application I'm working on, and it's really an `SPA`. I want to leverage Ember to do this so I have much more manageable code. All I really need Rails for is to ferry data back and forth on this page. Another reason for using Ember is so I don't have all of these nasty jQuery one-liner view templates written in JS (I prefer to use CoffeeScript).

I installed and configured Ember-CLI by following the instructions in the README for the `ember-cli-rails` gem. I have created a separate layout for any sections of my application that I want to use Ember. I have a route for `Products` set up to include the Ember JS and CSS resources. I can now see the "Welcome to Ember" message on the page for this route in my Rails application.

But I can't do anything else. I've tried to just create an "About" section for this little Ember application, which is called `products`. The problems I see so far:

- The ember-cli-rails gem initializer does not create a `views` directory. Why is that?
- I have yet to locate an `Ember-CLI` tutorial that doesn't have just a ton of assumptions built in.

I have an `about.js.coffeee` in my `<ember app>/routes` directory, one in `<ember app>/controllers` directory, one in a `<ember app>/views` directory that I had to create, and an `emblem` template in `<ember app>/templates` directory.

Now for a really basic question. How do I bring up this route in the browser? If I type in the route:

```
http://localhost:3000/products
```

I get my Ember page, as I should. But if I put:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/about
```

Then Rails tries to handle that route, of course. Which is not at all what I want. This is the step that is missing from the tutorials I have read. I would always recommend that a tutorial be put in front of a laymen in order to find the holes prior to publication. I would be happy to volunteer for that job in order to offer something to the community.

How do I navigate to an Ember route within my Rails application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You don't.

Back in the days there was `ember-rails` which let you setup ember through the Rails asset pipeline.

You could basically make it so that your root path in rails would render just enough html to kickstart ember. It was nice, and it just worked. But it was a pretty bad idea.

Ember now has its own build process through Ember-CLI so we don't need Sprockets or the asset pipeline just to serve up ember and its dependencies.

Ember also works perfectly fine deployed with just a static html file - you can just pass the request straight from Apache or NGINX (using mod_rewrite for example). SPA's only need just enough HTML to get the SPA framework rolling and then they fetch in data to populate the views.

If you engrained your Ember app into Rails the request would have to go through Rack all and all the middleware just to render what is basically a static html page - that's a lot of unnecessary overhead.

### Separate concerns.

The modern approach is to separate the front-end SPA and the backend API. They can even be developed by different teams. Having everything in one big repository was nice and cozy and you could just push to deploy - but separating the concerns makes better apps.

Not only will your front-end app load faster if it is not slugging through Rails. Your Rails API will run much faster if it can ditch all the parts related to serving assets, sessions and views. It becomes a mean green JSON machine instead of a slugging behemoth.

### Routing in ember.js

So load up `ember server` and get the [Ember Inspector plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi). Your route should be at `locahost:4200/about`

The ember development server will make sure every request to `localhost:4200` renders the index.html page.

If you try it with javascript disabled you will notice that any path on `locahost:4200` like `locahost:4200/foo/bar/baz` will render the same html.

But usually Ember will then parse the request url and pass it to your route handler.

This is how you declare a route handler in ember.js:

```
// app/router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about', { path: '/about' });
});
```

So when you `locahost:4200/about`.

Ember will render `templates/about.hbs`. As of Ember 2.0 views are out. Instead you have templates and components (think partials in Rails).

Ember will also load `app/routes/about.js` if it exists.

- http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/

Comment: I see with ```ember-cli-rails``` that it's easy to just point to wherever each Ember app is, so I get separating them out. Then that portion of my Rails application is just an API that can be accessed by anything. I think I am having a problem understanding the concept of an Ember route. There must be some sort of url that is passed to Ember, I don't know how. It apparently isn't through the browser's address bar. I have to tell Ember in the browser "Show me the About page" and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Edited with a bit more explanation on how to setup the routes. Learning ember is pretty frustrating because most tutorials are really out of date and it just changes so fast. The docs are also not so great. The best sources are the docs and http://discuss.emberjs.com/ has a good community.

Comment: There has also been a bunch of upheaval around what does what in Ember 2.0 so older tutorials often mention controllers and views which are not used very often today.